# How can I change tint of selected segment index on viewDidLoad? (Based on a Tutorial)

Tags: ios, subview, uisegmentedcontrol

I followed the following tutorial to change the color of a segmented control: 
http://goddess-gate.com/dc2/index.php/post/454

However, I am struggling to understand the code and load the view with a selected segment. On other words, I have managed to change the color of my segmented control to black, but it only happens when I select a segment and not when loading the view. When I load the view, it only appears in a color gray. Also, if I want to reset to the original gray color or change the color of the segmented Control in view will appear, how can I eliminate the black color and return to everything in gray and not selected?

Can someone point me out what exactly and why, do I need to add to the viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method?

Here is also the code:

```
NSInteger static compareViewsByOrigin(id sp1, id sp2, void *context)
{
// UISegmentedControl segments use UISegment objects (private API). Then we can safely
//   cast them to UIView objects.
float v1 = ((UIView *)sp1).frame.origin.x;
float v2 = ((UIView *)sp2).frame.origin.x;
if (v1 < v2)
    return NSOrderedAscending;
else if (v1 > v2)
    return NSOrderedDescending;
else
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

And the Action Method

```
-(IBAction)seleccionarSegmented:(id)sender {



int numSegments = [miSegmentedControl.subviews count];

for( int i = 0; i < numSegments; i++ ) {

    [[miSegmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:nil];
    [[miSegmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:200/255.0 green:200/255.0 blue:200/255.0 alpha:1]];
}

NSArray *sortedViews = [miSegmentedControl.subviews sortedArrayUsingFunction:compareViewsByOrigin context:NULL];

[[sortedViews objectAtIndex:miSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex] setTintColor: [UIColor blackColor]];

for (id view in miSegmentedControl.subviews) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}

for (id view in sortedViews) {
    [miSegmentedControl addSubview:view];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of swift 3 put this code inside `viewDidLoad()` or `ViewDidAppear()`

```
//this sets the value of the index that you want to call
let segmentedControlIBOutlet = 0

//this calls the actions for that index
segmentedControlAction(segmentedControlIBOutlet as AnyObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

In -viewDidLoad, try calling `[self seleccionarSegmented:miSegmentedControl]` (hopefully I've got the names right.